# so or such useful information

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Should "so" or "such" be used in the following?

> He gave us so/such useful information that we found the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proposed construction, you have to use "such." The word "so" can't be applied directly to an attributive adjective (i.e. an adjective that directly modifies a noun).

However, if you rearrange so that the adjective is separated from the noun, you can use "so":

> The information he gave was so useful that we found the answer
> quickly.